# BizTalk Databases Missing, Not sure what to do

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk

I was testing my code changes, meaning undeploying/redeploying applications in Biztalk and then all of the BizTalk databases disappeared (BAMAcrhive, BAMPrimaryImport, BiztalkDTADb, BizTalkMgmtDb, BizTalkMsgBoxDb, BizTalkRulEngineDb, BTAHL7). This is my test environment however, i did not have any backups of these databases (yes i have learned my lesson).

I tried restoring databases from another test environment and then updating the server names and what not within the tables. I tried stopping/deleting some applications in the console but I get more errors that come up.

I am assuming that the GUIDs/Keys of the deployed applications in TESTSERVER1 and TESTSERVER2 are different therefore it won't delete properly.

I am currently getting this error"Schema referenced by Map 'XXXXX' has been deleted. The local, cached version of the BizTalk Server group configuration is out of date. You must refresh the BizTalk Server group configuration before making further changes. (Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn)".

When I try to refresh the BizTalk Group in the console, i get the above error as well as "The application does not exist"

I tried truncating the tables that consisted of this data but there are too many references to go through the trouble.

I have also tried to restore the SSO key. Updated services (Biztalk, SSO, and a few more). When i try to start the BizTalk Service BizTalk Group: BizTalkServerApplication. It says the service has started and stopped.

So a few questions:

1. What should i do? I hope a re-installation of BizTalk is last resort.
2. How did the databases disappear in the first place, the undeployment scripts have nothing to do with the databases, only applications

Sorry if the solution is obvious, I am by no means a BizTalk Developer. Just a stressed junior BI developer on a friday night.

Answer (score 0):

if you already lost the Biztalk environnements(undeployed applications + DBs lost), the best choice is to reinstall your environment and setup a backup just after. but try to understand the source proble in windows and sql server logs.